# Case Statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Case statement below is not working when the condition met.

```
Dim TemplatePick As String

Select Case TemplatePick

Case OptCreate.Value = True
Call WebFormInfo

Case OptModify = True
Call ModifyTemplate

' many more case statement to come 
End Select
```

Comment: Select case is used to test the one value in this case `TemplatePick` then the Case would be `Case "A"` which would fire when `TemplatePick` = "A"

Comment: Your test case (TemplatePick) doesn't match your conditions (after case statements). Learn more [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php).

Comment: If you're trying to implement possibly multiple conditional statements, you'll need `If` statements instead of a `Case` switch.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you describe what you think should be happening?

Answer (score 3):

Select case is used to test the one value in this case `TemplatePick` then the Case would be `Case "A"` which would fire when `TemplatePick` = "A"

So for this to work:

```
Select Case True

Case OptCreate.Value
Call WebFormInfo

Case OptModify 
Call ModifyTemplate

' many more case statement to come 
End Select
```

Now one caveat with Select Case, once it finds a match it ignores all others.  In other words if `OptCreate.Value` is True then it will stop and not test whether `OptModify` is True.

Comment: `Select Case True` ??

Comment: @DavidZemens Yup, it basically turns the case statements into `ELSEIF` statements.

Comment: Interesting... so it will continue processing on `False` cases until it hits the first `True` case.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes, just like ElseIf.  It will test in order then stop as soon as one is true.  This is standard for Select Case in general.  As soon as one resolves as true it stops searching.

Comment: Neat. I've never used it this way before :)

Answer (score 3):

Your case test expression (TemplatePick) is not the same as your expresion list (OptCreate.Value, OptMOdify). I have a hard time even understanding what your are trying to do. Properly structured it would look something like this:

```
Dim TemplatePick As String

Select Case TemplatePick

Case "Template 1"
 Call WebFormInfo
Case "Template 2"
 Call ModifyTemplate
...
case Else
  'Do default behavior
End Select
```

More resources https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx